# What is the role of `train=True` in H2O model_performance()?

Tags: python, machine-learning, h2o

At first I thought `model_performance(train=True)` gives the performance result of predicting on the same data that we trained the model. But this is not the case, because the number must have been the same as  `model.model_performance(test_data=train)`, but it isn't.

Consider the following toy example:

```py
# Make a dataframe
df = h2o.H2OFrame({'a':list(range(100)), 'b':list(range(100, 0, -1)), 'c':list(range(0, 200, 2))})

# Split the data
train, val, test = df.split_frame([.6, .2], seed=0)

# Build a model
from h2o.estimators.random_forest import H2ORandomForestEstimator
model = H2ORandomForestEstimator(seed=0)

# Train the model
model.train(x=train.names[:-1], y=train.names[-1], training_frame=train, validation_frame=val)

# Get performance results
print(model.model_performance(train=True)['mae'] 
      , model.model_performance(valid=True)['mae']
      , model.model_performance(test_data=test)['mae']
     )
# 1.3816 1.1968 1.4722
```

Compare the results with

```py
print(model.model_performance(test_data=train)['mae'] 
      , model.model_performance(test_data=val)['mae']
      , model.model_performance(test_data=test)['mae']
     )
# 0.5548 1.1968 1.4722
```

Note that the result of `model_performance(train=True)` and `model_performance(test_data=train)` are different, but the result of `model_performance(valid=True)` and `model_performance(test_data=val)` are the same.

So I'm wondering whether `model_performance(train=True)` and `model.model_performance(test_data=train)` should be the same (and there is a mistake in the calculation in H2O code), or the purpose of `model_performance(train=True)` is something else.

In the [docs](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/master/3574/docs-website/h2o-py/docs/model_categories.html?highlight=model_performance#h2o.model.model_base.ModelBase.model_performance) it says

> **train: boolean, optional**
>   Report the training metrics for the model.
>   **valid: boolean, optional**
>   Report the validation metrics for the model.

But this is not very clear, given the above mentioned facts.

Answer (score 2):

`train=True` shows the models performance at the end of the training which means tthat it returns the training metric constructed during training while `test_data = train` sends the `train` data to the model for prediction and checks models performance on that prediction.

Comment: Please give more detail on the first part. Also I think any answer should explain why `valid=True` and `test_data=val` are the same while their training counterparts are different.

Comment: See https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/f5e48a608ec2bea7e2047b8dcf190700646b58a4/h2o-py/h2o/model/model_base.py#L336 for the actual code

Comment: @LoMaPh When using `train=True` or `valid=True` it is reporting the value on that data set from training. It is a helper function to extract just one bit of information.
When you give a data set, it instead makes predictions using it. With the validation data set the results are obviously identical, as it was evaluated at the end of training. (From memory the training error is the error during training, not at the end, which would explain why it is worse.)

Comment: I can't (quickly) find a good reference on that, but did find https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/TN-9  which shows how it is different when using balanced_classes, at least.

Comment: A possible reason why validation `mae` remains same is because during training, the model never learns from the validation data. It makes prediction on the validation set for tuning parameters both during training and testing, hence same result.